# SQL JOIN clause: substituting a bunch of flags with one Enum

Tags: grammar, xtext

I'm trying to implement a DSL containing some parts of SQL `SELECT` queries.

The `JOIN` syntax between two tables is specified (e.g. for [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)) like this:

```
// one of theese:
[ INNER ] JOIN
LEFT [ OUTER ] JOIN
RIGHT [ OUTER ] JOIN
FULL [ OUTER ] JOIN
CROSS JOIN
```

Note the optional keywords.

The following Xtext grammar works (sort of):

```
Join:
    'INNER'? inner?='JOIN'
|   left?='LEFT' 'OUTER'? 'JOIN'
|   right?='RIGHT' 'OUTER'? 'JOIN'
|   full?='FULL' 'OUTER'? 'JOIN'
|   cross?='CROSS' 'JOIN'
;
```

The model inference will of course create a bunch of flags which cannot be handled nicely later.

What I **really** want is an enum like this:

```
enum JoinType: INNER_JOIN | LEFT_JOIN | RIGHT_JOIN | FULL_JOIN | CROSS_JOIN;
```

I want an enum because:

- The generator et al. can use a simple `switch` statement.
- The processing of the optional keywords and the embedded whitespace is grammar work.

Is there any reasonable way to connect that enum to the rest of the grammar?

Answer (score 0):

You can define them individually, it may not be as elegant as enum although it is a way around;

```
Join:
 (joins += JoinType)+ // or however you wish
;
JoinTypes:
 INNER_JOIN | LEFT_JOIN | RIGHT_JOIN | FULL_JOIN | CROSS_JOIN
;
```

Then define each of them as well of you want.

```
 INNER_JOIN:
 // whatever you want, optional keywords etc.
;
 LEFT_JOIN:
...
```

Comment: Using your grammer I get an EClass `Join` with a feature `joins` which has the type `EString`. Then I would have to manually evaluate the string by hand including the optional keywords and perhaps even whitepspace. This is exactly the annoying part I want to shove to Xtext/ANTLR/... :-)

Comment: It is not like enum but for example if you use Xtend to code generate, when parsing you can get as whole. Although it may not be as convenient as direct enum when you are coding, it is like parsing enum in the background as you can get an enum type. Also it won't be like a String in the front side. Intellisense will expect you to obey one of join rules and there will be code complete according to your rules. Still, it won't be like exact enum you want :)

Comment: If I would use _only_ Xtend for generating / processing then I could use my original grammar and encapsulate the mapping between the flags and the enum into a convenient extension. Your proposal is similar but trades the processing of the original booleans for processing strings. Since at this point a boolean is already a higher-value representation than strings I don't consider this a good deal.